# ListView not reloading after data delete

Tags: android, android-listview

I have set the custom BaseAdapter in Activity as :

```
llNoContactMessage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llNoContacts);
    listAdapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, contactsList);
    lvContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContactList);
    lvContactList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    lvContactList.setOnItemClickListener(null);
```

And there is my Adapter class:

```
public class ContactsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<ContactsInfo> contactList;
private Context context;

public ContactsListAdapter(Context context, List<ContactsInfo> contactsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = contactsList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ContactsInfo contactsInfo = contactList.get(position);

    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.tvContactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
        vh.tvContactNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvContactNumber);
        vh.llRemoveContact = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llRemoveContact);

        view.setTag(vh);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.tvContactName.setText(contactsInfo.getContactName());
    holder.tvContactNumber.setText(contactsInfo.getContactNumber());
    holder.llRemoveContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UIUtils.showRemoveContactAlert(context, contactsInfo);
            if(UIUtils.contactRemoved) {
                contactList.remove(contactsInfo);
                setList(getContacts());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvContactNumber;
    TextView tvContactName;
    LinearLayout llRemoveContact;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public ContactsInfo getItem(int index) {
    return contactList.get(index);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).get_id();
}

public void setList(List<ContactsInfo> list) {
    contactList.clear();
    contactList.addAll(list);
}

private List<ContactsInfo> getContacts() {
    CrisisCallingDatabase crisisCallDB = new CrisisCallingDatabase(context);

    return crisisCallDB.getContactsList();
}
```

}

The method to delete data from database is:

```
public static void showRemoveContactAlert(final Context context, final ContactsInfo contact) {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    b.setMessage("Remove Contact");
    b.setCancelable(true);
    b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            CrisisCallingDatabase ccd = new CrisisCallingDatabase(context);
            if(ccd.deletContact(contact.get_id())){
                Toast.makeText(context, contact.getContactName() + " removed successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contactRemoved = true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Remove contact failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contactRemoved = false;
            }
            CrisisCallingDatabase.closeDBConnections();
        }
    });
    b.setNegativeButton("No", null);
    b.show();
}
```

But the view of the list is not removing the item from the list. However after clicking the any UI component on the list again is reloading the list i.e. the deleted item is removed. I don't know where I did mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: CrisisCallingDatabase crisisCallDB = new CrisisCallingDatabase(context);

    return crisisCallDB.getContactsList();   remove it from here as well

Comment: @Triode I have updated my question with the method to delete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue, I just moved the confirmation alert code inside the On Click event like below :

```
holder.llRemoveContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    b.setMessage("Remove Contact");
                    b.setCancelable(true);
                    b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if(succefulRemoval)){
                                contactList.remove(contactsInfo);
                                setList();
                                Toast.makeText(context, contactsInfo.getContactName() + " removed successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Remove contact failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    b.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                    b.show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your **notifyDataSetChanged()** call to the end of your **setList** method.

Comment: Example code for notifying the view of the changed data: http://android.codota.com/scenarios/51891664da0a0f60f8605bc1/android.widget.ArrayAdapter?tag=out_2013_05_05_07_19_34

Comment: @Mike could not see any effect. Actually list is reloading while saving new items but not on deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got answer already, but just for an extra

```
public void setList(List<ContactsInfo> list) {
contactList.clear();
contactList.addAll(list);
contactList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```